# How to remove ambiguity due to having both an `and` and an `or` in a sentence

Tags: ambiguity, coordinating-conjunctions

I have two questions related to the following sentence.

`I have an apple or an orange and a banana`

First I would like to confirm that the sentence is ambiguous because it could mean one of the following

- I have (i) an apple or (ii) an orange and a banana.
- I have (i) an apple and a banana or (ii) an orange and a banana.

Second, I would like to remove the ambiguity by making it mean the former. What are some ways to do this?

Comment: Your way is fine. This has been covered here before; there is a trade-off between clarity and stylishness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Can you link to a question that's covered this.

Comment: This calls for belt and suspenders - "I have either an apple or both an orange and banana." - Add *either*, add *both* and delete the *a* in front of banana.

Comment: [Precedence of 'and' and 'or'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32242/precedence-of-and-and-or) covers some of the relevant material. A problem is that examples either get involved or sound like logic grade 1 lessons. Here, a comma in the right place disambiguates, but doesn't stop the sentence sounding ridiculous in normal conversation / looking ridiculous outside a class looking at logic.

Comment: Other threads (and these are proving hard to find) suggest shenanigans like 'You can have bacon & eggs or fish & chips, and peaches & cream.' If style is unimportant, brackets may be used as per the maths convention: (i)  I have {an apple} or {an orange and a banana}. But in running text, workarounds are obviously better. I have either just an apple, or both an orange and a banana.

Comment: Thanks. Both "I have either an apple or both an orange and banana" and the link provide good enough answers i.e. ''I have an apple, or an orange and a banana.''

Comment: Another possibility is to duplicate a preposition (e.g. "of") : *I am in possession of an apple or of an orange and a banana*.

Comment: Not sure why simple commas aren't getting more attention here, but I see that you found them

Comment: @Unrelated  'Here, a comma in the right place disambiguates,' is sufficient attention for this simple example in a site aimed at linguists.

Answer (score 1):

This is why English has *either* and *both*.

*I have **either** an apple or **both** an orange and a banana.*

Comment: Just to wanted to also give credit to @PhilSweet who put ''I have either an apple or both an orange and banana'' as a possible solution in the comments above.